# Magento 2 programmatically online refund

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, sales-order, refund, transaction

I'm trying to make online refund using this method:

```
// \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice $_invoiceModel
// \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\CreditmemoFactory $_creditmemoFactory
// \Magento\Sales\Model\Service\CreditmemoService $_creditmemoService

$invoiceobj = $this->_invoiceModel->loadByIncrementId('000000073');
$creditmemoObject = $this->_creditmemoFactory->createByOrder($order);
$creditmemoObject->setInvoice($invoiceobj);
$this->_creditmemoService->refund($creditmemoObject);
```

And I'm receiving following error:

```
We don't have enough information to save the parent transaction ID.
```

Comment: try createByInvoice instead of  createByOrder and pass the invoice object to it and $creditmemo->setInvoice($invoiceobj); do  not need anymore

Answer (score 3):

Try the service layer. This interface was added in 2.1.3 for exactly this purpose:

[\Magento\Sales\Api\RefundInvoiceInterface](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1-develop/app/code/Magento/Sales/Api/RefundInvoiceInterface.php)

```
// Inject \Magento\Sales\Api\RefundInvoiceInterface $invoiceRefunder
$invoiceRefunder->execute(
    123, // Invoice ID (NOTE: not increment ID)
    [], // Items array (default all)
    true // Online refund--send to payment gateway
);
```

There are several additional optional arguments for notifying the customer and adding a comment.

If you're curious, you can find the implementation here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1-develop/app/code/Magento/Sales/Model/RefundInvoice.php#L127

Comment: I tried that method too. I placed entity_id instead increment ID but still receiving same error: main.CRITICAL: Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException: We don't have enough information to save the parent transaction ID. in /data/web/magento2/vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/ResourceModel/Order/Payment/Transaction.php:145

Comment: Also I debug it and my $txnId is set to zero. What is $txnId? If I try to make online refund from Magento admin panel - it works perfect. But from my code - no

Comment: What payment method?

Comment: Authorize.NET CIM - authorize and capture